# Merge two rows into one with same columns and add columns values

Tags: mysql

I have two queries which return the same row structure in 2 rows:

```
mc_name        ENE FEB MAR ABR MAY JUN JUL AGO SEP OCT NOV DIC TOTAL
TOTAL CANTIDAD   0   0   4  55  28  74 112 175 120 123   0   0   691
TOTAL CANTIDAD   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   3   8   7   0   0    21
```

With `UNION` I can return both rows but I need to merge both rows into one and add column values for each column expect the first one which is a reference.

How can I achieve this:

```
mc_name        ENE FEB MAR ABR MAY JUN JUL AGO SEP OCT NOV DIC TOTAL
TOTAL CANTIDAD   0   0   4  55  28  75 114 178 128 130   0   0   712
```

Both queries, with `UNION` below:

```
select
  'TOTAL CANTIDAD' AS 'mc_name',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(properties.created_at) = 1, 1, 0)) as ENE,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 2, 1, 0)) AS FEB,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 3, 1, 0)) as MAR,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 4, 1, 0)) AS ABR,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 5, 1, 0)) AS MAY,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 6, 1, 0)) as JUN,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 7, 1, 0)) as JUL,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 8, 1, 0)) AS AGO,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 9, 1, 0)) as SEP,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 10, 1, 0)) as OCT,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 11, 1, 0)) as NOV,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 12, 1, 0)) as DIC,
  COUNT(PROPERTIES.PROP_EXCLUSIVE) AS TOTAL
from
  `properties`
  left join `megaagents` on `properties`.`megaagent_id` = `megaagents`.`id`
where
  `properties`.`prop_currency` = 'USD'
  and `properties`.`marketcenter_id` = 11
  and `properties`.`prop_exclusive` in ('No Exclusiva', 'Exclusiva')
  and `properties`.`prop_transaction` in ('Alquiler Temporal', 'Alquiler', 'Venta')
UNION
select
  'TOTAL CANTIDAD' AS 'mc_name',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(properties.created_at) = 1, 1, 0)) as ENE,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 2, 1, 0)) AS FEB,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 3, 1, 0)) as MAR,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 4, 1, 0)) AS ABR,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 5, 1, 0)) AS MAY,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 6, 1, 0)) as JUN,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 7, 1, 0)) as JUL,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 8, 1, 0)) AS AGO,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 9, 1, 0)) as SEP,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 10, 1, 0)) as OCT,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 11, 1, 0)) as NOV,
  SUM(IF(month(properties.created_at) = 12, 1, 0)) as DIC,
  COUNT(PROPERTIES.PROP_EXCLUSIVE) AS TOTAL
from
  `properties`
  left join `users` on `properties`.`prop_capper_email` = `users`.`email_local_crm`
  left join `team_user` on `users`.`id` = `team_user`.`user_id`
  left join `teams` on `team_user`.`team_id` = `teams`.`id`
where
  `properties`.`prop_currency` = 'USD'
  and `properties`.`marketcenter_id` = 11
  and `properties`.`prop_exclusive` in ('No Exclusiva', 'Exclusiva')
  and `properties`.`prop_transaction` in ('Alquiler Temporal', 'Alquiler', 'Venta') 
  AND `teams`.`team_name` = 'Productividad'
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: There are overlaps between the two groups, so you will probably need to use `UNION`, one way or another. Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the desired result

Comment: Note that `left join x... where x... = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: @GMB 5.7 version